# Método Post não está rodando no Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Criando um método **POST** e testando pelo **Postman**, não consigo acessar o **Controller** desse **POST**. Não implementei ainda muita coisa, mas deveria parar no **Break** se, claro, estivesse funcionando.
Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class OptOutClientController : Controller
{
    private IOptOutCreateService optOutCreateService;

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public OptOutClientController(IOptOutCreateService optOutCreateService)
    {
        this.optOutCreateService = optOutCreateService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OptOutPostClient([FromBody]OptOutRequest client)
    { **Breakpoint nessa chave e não entra **

        if (client == null)                                                                                          
            throw new OptOutException( "Favor informar os dados do OptOut!");

        var result = await optOutCreateService.Process(new OptOutCreateCommand(client.Cpf, client.Email, client.Telefone, client.Bandeira, client.Canal));

        return Ok(new ApiReturnItem<OptOutResult> { Item = result, Success = true });
    }
}
```

Screenshot do **Postman** executando o método **POST**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT1**

Fiz um pequeno exemplo sem nada, apenas um controller e nada mais e tenho o mesmo erro:
Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddRouting();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
            });
        }
    }
```

controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult postar()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Postman
url:http://localhost:51553/api/home/postar
body: {"teste": "1"}

E obtenho o mesmo erro de page not found

Comment: coloque outros breakpoints, o seu post está indo para a API e retornando um erro 500, o que representa uma falha no lado do servidor. Talvez a Excessão esteja ocorrendo antes mesmo de entrar em sua action.

Comment: E confira as rotas, observando que você está usando `[Route("api/[controller]")]` e o seu post é apenas para `/api/OptOutClient`, não deveria ser para `/api/OptOutClient/OptOutPostClient` ???

Comment: Ok, @LeandroAngelo, sim, mas mesmo assim não rolou. Eu já havia colocado isso e também não estava funcionando.

Comment: Procure e verifique também o `RegisterRoutes` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, coloquei outros break e nada e o erro no **Postman** é de Page Not Found(404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explicação

Você atribuiu uma rota ao `Controller` mas não atribuiu para a `Action`, neste caso, é atribuido o [Roteamento Convencional](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#conventional-routing). Neste tipo de roteamento, por padrão, é utilizado o nome da `Action` para construção da rota.

No seu caso, você não está inserindo o trecho da rota responsável por direcionar a `Action` (`OptOutPostClient`)

## Solução

Altere o `POST` direcionando para a rota abaixo:

```
http://localhost:51585/api/OptOutClient/OptOutPostClient
```

Caso não tenha uma rota padrão aplicada, coloque da seguinte forma:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });
```

Comment: ou simplesmente renomeie o método `OptOutPostClient` para `Post`, caso não houver outras action utilizando o mesmo verbo

Comment: Jean, bom dia. Mesmo colocando o nome da Action no Postman, continuo não chegando ao Break

Comment: O build está configurado como Debug ou Release? Se estiver como Release, altere para Debug.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates, Debug e o no meu Startup.cs já configurei para aceitar as rotas: `services.AddMvc();
services.AddRouting();` e também `app.UseMvc();`

Comment: Atualizei a resposta

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates, continuo com 404, porem naquelas palavrinhas(esqueci o nome) acima da declaração da classe, diz que eu obtive X solicitações, antes estava com 0 solicitações.

Comment: pnet, tente tirar o atributo [Route("api/[controller]")]

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, marquei a sua resposta, mas só funciona sem a Action na URL, mesmo mapeando a rota no Startup. Se puder editar isso, agradeço.

Comment: Apenas para tentar solucionar esse problema, tudo acontece do erro 500 é quando eu injeto uma dependência no construtor do Controller.

Comment: Você configurou a implementação no Startup.cs?